# SQL Find all events that occurred within 1 day of each other

Tags: sql, join, hive

I have a table as such in Hive:
dt (timestamp), event_id(string)

I'm looking for all events that happened within (say) one day of each other for the same session. Assume that a single session can span over multiple days.

```
   session         dt                    event_id
       1      2016-06-10 00:07:33     u38443jdnksdjoeoewk
       2      2016-06-11 11:11:41     u39839jdijewenkfjij
       1      2016-06-15 13:07:42     u38443jdjdksdnlqpma
       2      2016-06-12 05:08:07     u38443jmcmsdjwewekh
```

In this case the resultant set would be

```
2016-06-11 11:11:41     u39839jdijewenkfjij
2016-06-12 05:08:07     u38443jmcmsdjwewekh
```

as the other rows' timestamps were beyond a day. This looks to be doable via a self join but that would be very expensive. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

Your best method to get all events within a day of any given even is to use a self join. Computationally, it would not be that expensive.  I tested it out on a table with 7000 records and when matching at plus or minus 60 minutes it took 3 seconds and returned 176,588 results.  I used DATEDIFF for comparison or you can use DATEADD and compare to both limits.  Here are both examples using your table:

```
SELECT h1.session, h1.event_id, h2.session, h2.event_id, h1.dt, h2.dt
FROM Hive h1
    JOIN Hive h2 ON DATEDIFF(hh, h1.dt, h2.dt) < 24


SELECT h1.session, h1.event_id, h2.session, h2.event_id, h1.dt, h2.dt
FROM Hive h1
    JOIN Hive h2 ON DATEADD(d,1,h1.dt) >= h2.dt
        AND DATEADD(d,-1,h1.dt) <= h2.dt
```

Comment: could you share the query you used?

Comment: @Craig I added two queries. I would test both, I think depending on your circumstance and if the dt column has an index, the second option might be faster. In testing it, the second option was slower.

Comment: this doesnt take into account date ordering, need to use `ABS()` around the `DATEDIFF(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Use `lag` and `lead` to get the previous and next row's dates and subtract it with the current row's date. Check to see if either of them is within one day of the current row's date.

```
select session,dt,event_id 
from (
select dt,event_id,session,
unix_timestamp(dt)-unix_timestamp(lag(dt) over(partition by session order by dt)) prev_diff,
unix_timestamp(lead(dt) over(partition by session order by dt))-unix_timestamp(dt) next_diff
from t
) x
where prev_diff <= 86400 or next_diff <= 86400
```

Comment: Apologies @vkp, there was an error in the previous schema. Updated the question - essentially, looking for rows with the same session id

Comment: @Craig ..see the edit..the only change needed was partitioning by session.

Comment: @vkp I am not sure if this works since there could be many records that are within an hour of the current record.  Also, they may not be in chronological order.  Best case, lag and lead would give you 2 of many possible records that are within 1 hour of the current record.